# had better to get or had better get

Tags: sentence-construction

The sentence is

**Travellers  ________________ their reservation well in advance if they want to fly during winter vacation.**

Which is suitable to complete this sentence. Please give some explanation so that I can understand.

**1. had better to get**

**2. had better get**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Had better** is a construction called "modal idiom" by Quirk et al. It works like a modal verb, but not exactly.

It works like a modal verb in that it is followed by an infinitive without the particle **to**:

> Travellers **had better get** their reservation well in advance if they want to fly during winter vacation.

You can substitute it with some other modal verb, it will also not require the use of **to**

> Travellers **will get** their reservation... (*modal verb **will**: no need to use the particle **to***)
>   Travellers **must get** their reservation... (*modal verb **must**: no need to use the particle **to***)

There is another *modal idiom* that works like "*had better*": "*would rather*" -

> Travellers **would rather get** their reservation well in advance than wait until the last moment. (see, it uses no **to** too)

There are two *modal idioms* that use **to**: "*have got to*" and "*be to*" -

> Travellers **have got to get** their reservation well in advance, or they might loose their chance to fly.
>   Travellers **are to get** their reservation well in advance under a new law.

The meanings of these idioms are slightly different but what's important for your question is that only two of them use the particle **to**.

---

Reference: Quirk et al., *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, Topic 3.45, "Modal Idioms", page 141