# “The world better have strong leader” vs. “The world better has strong leader”

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

- > The world better have strong leader
- > The world better has strong leader

What's the correct way?

1. The first one("have") sounds me the correct, but I can't explain why.
2. *The world* = *it*, therefore I wonder if it should be "has".

Comment: A single leader, or more than one?

Comment: Hey @Nathan Tuggy. A single leader

Comment: The world should better have a strong leader. This is about the future, you can't use Present Simple here. Consider: You better do your homework. And You better did your homework (incorrect).

Comment: I think this is a colloquial version of "had better", that why "have" sounds better. But I think neither of your sentences is idiomatic. And you have to say "**a** strong leader".

Comment: @user178049 right on spot!

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for an idiomatic version, **neither**, but your first option is closer to being grammatical.

You should use, and maybe unintentionally are using "had better".

"had better" is [what Quirk et al. call a modal idiom](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44072/had-better-to-get-or-had-better-get). I checked, and CamGEL considers it as idiom-like as well. That means **it's normally colloquially fixed** and you don't usually see different inflections, such as *has better*, unless perhaps for humorous effect.

So the grammatical sentence is

> The world ***had better*** have **a** strong leader.

However, it's also common in informal registers for the *had* to be dropped, resulting in

> The world ***better*** have **a** strong leader.

As a side note, your main verb, *have*, sounds a bit odd. Consider if "find" would be more appropriate for your sentence.

c.f.

> You better run!